# Why Timer/Countdown always reset with initial value in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am Creating Countdown timer in TableViewCell. and it is working perfectly. but when I scroll down and then scroll up than cell timer being reset with the initial value. I am not understanding what I do here so it will not refresh or reset with the initial value. Please help me any buddy got it.

My TableViewCell Class Code is:

```
class DealOfferCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var CellCardView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var CellBurgerKingImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var CellImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var CellGetOffLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var CellOnAWhopperLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var CellDealEndsOnLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var CellDealItemNameLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var DealLeftButton: UIButton!

    private var timer: Timer?
    fileprivate var timeCounter: Double = 0

    var expiryTimeInterval: TimeInterval? {
        didSet {
            if timer == nil
            {
                startTimer()
                RunLoop.current.add(timer!, forMode: .commonModes)
            }
        }
    }

    private func startTimer() {
        if let interval = expiryTimeInterval {
            timeCounter = interval
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                timer = Timer(timeInterval: 1.0,
                              repeats: true,
                              block: { [weak self] _ in
                                guard let strongSelf = self else {
                                    return
                                }
                                strongSelf.onComplete()
                })
            } else {
                timer = Timer(timeInterval: 1.0,
                              target: self,
                              selector: #selector(onComplete),
                              userInfo: nil,
                              repeats: true)
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func onComplete() {
        guard timeCounter >= 0 else {
            // btnGoForTest.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            CellDealEndsOnLabel.text = "Time ended."
            timer?.invalidate()
            timer = nil
            return
        }

        // btnGoForTest.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let hours = Int(timeCounter) / 3600
        let minutes = Int(timeCounter) / 60 % 60
        let seconds = Int(timeCounter) % 60

        CellDealEndsOnLabel.text = "DEAL ENDS ON " + String(format:"%02i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds)

        timeCounter -= 1
        print("\(timeCounter)")
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        timer?.invalidate()

        timer = nil
    }
}
```

And code inside CellForIndexPath :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = DealsOffersTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MapCell", for: indexPath) as! MapCell
    let getTime1 : Double = Double(500)
    cell.expiryTimeInterval = getTime1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not store volatile data like an expiration date in a cell. Cells get discarded and reused as the user scrolls around. You should store your expiration date in a data model object (typically an array.) Then in your `tableView(_: cellForRowAt:)` method, you should fetch the data from your model and use it to configure the cell.

Your code is not working because you're trying to make `expiryTimeInterval` a property of the cell. When you scroll, cells that scroll off the screen get recycled and reused to display data for different indexPaths.